# Bootstrap element not clickable with selenium python

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, selenium

I have a Bootstrap close button:

```
<div class="col-md-6 box">
 <div class="col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4">Mode</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <button type="button" id="close_tag" class="close quit-erase" aria-label="Close">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
 </div>  
 <div class="col-md-12">         
 </div>  
</div>
```

When it is clicked it is supposed to make the class `box` disappear which works fine with the mouse cursor. However, no matter how I address it with selenium, it doesn't work (I am using [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase):

```
element = self.selenium.find_element_by_id("close_tag")
element.click()
```

The code doesn't break, but it also doesn't close. I tried `xpath` and `css_selector`, too, with the same result. There are no hidden menus or `iframes` anywhere on the page and from Google's inspector tool, there isn't anything overlaying over it. I also tried to put the `id` on the parent elements:

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="close_tag">
  <button type="button"  class="close quit-erase" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <button type="button"  class="close quit-erase" aria-label="Close">
    <span id="close_tag" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

However, none of  them seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains):

**driver**: The WebDriver instance which performs user actions.

```
click(on_element=None)
```

Clicks an element.

Args :  on_element: The element to click. If None, clicks on current mouse position.

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")
hidden_submenu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav #submenu1")
ActionChains(driver).click(hidden_submenu).perform()
```

Comment: sorry, I was not precise enough, there are no hidden menus, I the other 3 ids were just in case the `span` tag or `button` tag don't work, I''l update my question.

Comment: Still the way youre calling the method click() is not the correct. .click() by itself clicks where the mouse is, and .click(element) is the correct way to send a click event (to an element)

Comment: Are you sure? according to this http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#interacting-with-the-page `.click()` seems to work. It also works on other buttons just not on this one with the span tag. I also tried your suggested way, didn't beak the code but also didn't work

Comment: is your "self.selenium" bit valid? have you tried performing other actions with it, perhaps entering text or such? you can check if you're indeed selecting the tag by print(element.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

Comment: ahh, `get_attribute('innerHTML')` prints out `<span aria-hidden="true">×</span>` so it IS hidden.